# Modify content of iframe

Tags: iframe

If I have and iframe in html page, and within that iframe I need to remove a img tag.

Is it possible to manipulate contents of iframe that loads an external site?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

native security in browsers makes this quite difficult, but it can be done with cross domain messaging; take a look at this [library](http://easyxdm.net/wp/) : used it many times; it simply works